# Generate a row per minute of the day from a sparsely populated database table

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table populated with time stamped rows inserted at (essentially) random point in the day.

I need to generate running totals with 1 row per minute (so for a single day there will always be exactly 24 * 60 rows) e.g.

```
Date                Quantity    Running Total
2009-10-29 06:30           1                1
2009-10-29 06:31           5                6
2009-10-29 06:32           10              16  
2009-10-29 06:33           11              27   
2009-10-29 06:34           22              49
```

...
...

Any thoughts on the best way to do this? 
One SQL query would be ideal but not essential, performance is fairly important (sub 5 seconds on a table containg 500k rows of which 70k are interesting to this query)

My Final Solution (more or less).

The actual scenario was this. I have two tables one containing Orders with a 1:n relationship to a Fills table.

I needed to show the running Average Price and Cumulative Total for each minute in the trading day

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATETIME, @EndDate AS DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '2009-10-28';
SET @EndDate = '2009-10-29';

-- Generate a Temp Table containing all the dates I'm interested in
WITH DateIntervalsCTE AS
(
 SELECT 0 i, @StartDate AS Date
 UNION ALL
 SELECT i + 1, DATEADD(minute, i, @StartDate )
 FROM DateIntervalsCTE 
 WHERE DATEADD(minute, i, @StartDate ) < @EndDate
)
SELECT DISTINCT Date 
INTO #Dates
FROM DateIntervalsCTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);

SELECT 
 d.Date
 , mo3.symbol
 , ISNULL(SUM(mf.Quantity),0) AS CumulativeTotal
 , ROUND(ISNULL(SUM(mf.Quantity * mf.Price)/SUM(mf.Quantity),0),4) AS AveragePrice
FROM 
 #Dates AS d
 CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT mo2.Symbol, mo2.OrderID 
    FROM 
     Orders AS mo2 
     INNER JOIN Fills AS mf2 ON mo2.OrderID = mf2.OrderID
    WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),mf2.FillDate,101)) = @StartDate
    ) AS mo3
 LEFT JOIN Fills AS mf ON mo3.OrderID = mf.OrderID AND CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(16),mf.FillDate,120)) < = d.Date
WHERE
 d.Date >= DATEADD(mi,390, @StartDate) -- 06:30
 AND d.Date <= DATEADD(mi,780, @StartDate) -- 13:00
GROUP BY d.Date, mo3.symbol
ORDER BY mo3.Symbol, d.Date
```

I still haven't completed all my testing but this looks like it does the trick, thanks for the assistance!

Comment: PS: Pretty sure there is a solution to this in http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596009762/ but of course my copy is MIA :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure the date column has an index on it and performance should be reasonable.

```
SELECT t.Date,
COUNT(*) AS Quantity,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE Date < t.Date) AS RunningTotal
FROM Table t
GROUP BY t.Date
```

Getting a table populated with one row per minute can be done extremely quickly as follows:

```
DECLARE @StartDate smalldatetime
DECLARE @EndDate smalldatetime

SET @StartDate = '1 jan 2009' --MIN(TimeStamp) FROM Table
SET @EndDate = '2 jan 2009' --MAX(TimeStamp) FROM Table

SET @StartDate = DATEADD(minute,-DATEPART(minute,@StartDate),@StartDate)
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(minute,-DATEPART(minute,@EndDate),@EndDate)


; WITH DateIntervalsCTE AS
(
SELECT 0 i, @startdate AS Date
UNION ALL
SELECT i + 1, DATEADD(minute, i, @startdate )
FROM DateIntervalsCTE 
WHERE DATEADD(minute, i, @startdate ) <= @enddate
)
SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM DateIntervalsCTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);
```

Provided you only need < ~22 days worth of data due to recursion restrictions.

All you need now is to merge the two, using a temp table to hold data seems to be quickest

```
DECLARE @StartDate smalldatetime
DECLARE @EndDate smalldatetime
DECLARE @t TABLE (Date smalldatetime,Quantity int,RunningTotal int)
SET @StartDate = '1 jan 2009' --MIN(TimeStamp) FROM Table
SET @EndDate = '2 jan 2009' --MAX(TimeStamp) FROM Table

SET @StartDate = DATEADD(minute,-DATEPART(minute,@StartDate),@StartDate)
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(minute,-DATEPART(minute,@EndDate),@EndDate)


; WITH DateIntervalsCTE AS
(
SELECT 0 i, @startdate AS Date
UNION ALL
SELECT i + 1, DATEADD(minute, i, @startdate )
FROM DateIntervalsCTE 
WHERE DATEADD(minute, i, @startdate ) <= @enddate
)
INSERT INTO @t (Date) 
SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM DateIntervalsCTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);

UPDATE t SET Quantity = (SELECT COUNT(d.TimeStamp) FROM Table d WHERE Date = t.date)
from @t t

update t2 set runningtotal = (SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM @t WHERE date <= t2.date)
from @t t2

select * from @t
```

Comment: Thinking on, there has to be a CTE way to do this better.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely solves the running total part but I don't have a row for every minute, typically I'll get 10 rows in a second and then nothing for several minutes

Comment: So you need zeroes for the minutes without rows?

Comment: Thanks! This was enough for me to figure the rest out, been a while since I've written such a mind bending query. I'll post it here later once I've finished testing it

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use group by for sure.  The hard(ish) part is that it'll be synthetic, meaning you'll have to create it yourself.  There are a bunch of ways to do that

> > GROUP BY year(yourdate), month(yourdate), day(yourdate) etc...

Except I can't remember if there are hours() and minutes() functions off the top of my head.

You can also use the [datepart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function.

Then you can put those all together in one column for a nice looking label.