# SQL Temp Table Insert for every hour of day

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to write a query that will create a temp table and insert data for every hour of the day. Here is what I have so far

```
SELECT 
    [Shift], 
    Shift_name, 
    Machine, 
    [Start_Date], 
    end_Date, 
    Start_Time_Hour,
    end_time_hour
FROM 
    [dbo].[prd_Casting_Shift] 
WHERE
    ISNULL([Start_Date], '00:00:00.000') >= GETDATE() - 1
ORDER BY
    Start_Time_Hour,
    [Start_Date]
```

This works great at returning the data for the last 24 hours but I need it to account for every hour. So it needs to insert into a temp table. I think I need to use a loop with a counter. Not sure though how I would do this, I think my counter needs to represent the hour of the day and then do a insert based on hour

Comment: Sorry it did not grab all my code

Comment: SELECT 
 [Shift], 
 Shift_name, 
 Machine, 
 [Start_Date], 
 end_Date, 
 Start_Time_Hour,
 end_time_hour
FROM 
 [dbo].[prd_Casting_Shift] 
WHERE
 ISNULL([Start_Date], '00:00:00.000') >= GETDATE() - 1
ORDER BY
 Start_Time_Hour,
 [Start_Date]

Comment: To format large code blocks, copy and paste your data in, highlight the code, and hit the little code block button at the top. Alternatively, you can manually add 4 spaces to the beginning of each line.

Comment: When you say that you need it to account for every hour, what do you mean? Do you want the data aggregated at an hourly level? I think some sample data and desired output example would help us out a lot on this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a row per minute of the day from a sparsely populated database table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645274/generate-a-row-per-minute-of-the-day-from-a-sparsely-populated-database-table)

Comment: Use the answer from the duplicate, only do hours instead of minutes.

Comment: that thing is huge there is no way I need that

Comment: After further discussion with my co worker they need it to return per machine and per hour. So for every machine for that hour I need a row representing the data. My thought was figure out how to get one machine to generate per hour and I can figure out the rest. Just need some help getting it to generate a line per hour for 12 hours for one machine